# Hiding The excel logo when Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",False)" is run

Tags: excel, vba

When you hide the ribbon using VBA code
The Excel Logo is shown on the top left corner of the Window.
I want to suppress that and ideally load my own logo in its place

I have no clue where to begin with this

The code I use to hide the ribbon is:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",False)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now tested the code from Chip Pearson. It changes the icon on top left of the  window and also in the taskbar.
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SetIcon.aspx
I've tested it with the elephant icon from PostgreSQL db.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would post the image , however I don't know how to do that